# C++, Boost, how to get a path name that does not exist anymore?

Tags: c++, boost, path, filesystems

I'm using `boost::filesystem` to iterate through all of the directories and the files under the root(let say `C:\\`) path given.

I have used `recursive_directory_iterator` to initialize `vector<boost::filesystem::path>` paths that contains all of the paths under the root.

However some of paths have been removed from the directory and I'm printing a message saying "A path no longer exist, the path is..". But I'm not sure how to get a path name that is no longer exist(as I cannot access the vector to get the pathname).

code added as requested*

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < this->paths.size(); i++) {
    if (boost::filesystem::exists(this->paths[i])) {
        /* get a path from the list of path, ps */
        boost::filesystem::path p = this->paths[i];

        /* convert path to string */
        string path = p.string();

        /* check file size(should not be over 10MB) */
        if (get_file_size(path) > 10 * pow(10, 6)) continue;

        /* setting extension */
        string file_extension = boost::filesystem::extension(path);

        /* if current path stands for a text file */
        if (!file_extension.compare(this->extension)) notify_changes(p);
    } else {
        cout << "A path no longer exist, the path is.." << endl;
        this->paths.erase(this->paths.begin() + i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post some code? It's quite hard to tell what you are trying to do, and what you have accomplished already.

Comment: @elyashiv I've added a code that iterate through all of the paths inside of std::vector<boost::filesystem::path> and check if the current path exist or not. If exist, process the path otherwise, throw a message and print the path deleted as well.

Comment: How do you know a path no longer exists without knowing what it was before it was deleted?  That seems ... strange.  It also appears you're modifying the vector while you're iterating through it.  That likely won't work well.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Do you mean how do I know a path is deleted from a directory?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Oh, thanks for pointing that, I'll change my code as soon as my question is resolved.

Comment: @jsha114 *Do you mean how do I know a path is deleted from a directory?*  You're asking what the path is, right?  If you don't know what the path is, how do you know it no longer exists?  That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @AndrewHenle That's because I've initialized all the paths under a given directory. So the vector<path> is containing more than a thousand of paths(possibly more). Before processing all the paths, once a path is removed from a directory, the path will no longer be able to accessed by paths[i] as it does not exist. Then, I need to find which path has been removed from the directory.

Comment: @jsha114 [`path::string()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_33_1/libs/filesystem/doc/path.htm#string) or even `native_file_string()` and `native_directory_string()` aren't returning the full name to the file that was deleted?

Answer (score 0):

### Loops

The old school loop approach:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2aca75bd69b4def9)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

int main() {
    if (system("bash -c 'mkdir -pv tree/{a,b,c}/subdir/; touch tree/{a,b,c}/subdir/{a,b,c}.txt'"))
        perror("whoops");

    std::vector<fs::path> paths { fs::recursive_directory_iterator { "tree/" }, {} };

    if (system("bash -c 'rm -rfv tree/b/subdir/ tree/*/subdir/b.txt'"))
        perror("whoops");

    for (auto it = paths.begin(); it != paths.end();) {
        auto& p = *it;
        if (!fs::exists(p))
        {
            std::cout << "No longer exists: " << p << "\n";
            it = paths.erase(it);
            continue;
        }

        // DO PROCESSING

        ++it;
    }
}
```

### Using Algorithms

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e452f2d5be88f112)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/range/algorithm.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace fs = boost::filesystem;

bool try_to_process(fs::path const& p) // return false if file wasn't found
{
    if (!fs::exists(p))
    {
        std::cout << "No longer exists: " << p << "\n";
        return false;
    }

    // DO PROCESSING

    return true;
}

int main() {
    if (system("bash -c 'mkdir -pv tree/{a,b,c}/subdir/; touch tree/{a,b,c}/subdir/{a,b,c}.txt'"))
        perror("whoops");

    std::vector<fs::path> paths { fs::recursive_directory_iterator { "tree/" }, {} };

    if (system("bash -c 'rm -rfv tree/b/subdir/ tree/*/subdir/b.txt'"))
        perror("whoops");

    paths.erase(boost::stable_partition(paths, try_to_process), paths.end());
}
```

### Outputs

Prints

```
mkdir: created directory `tree'
mkdir: created directory `tree/a'
mkdir: created directory `tree/a/subdir/'
mkdir: created directory `tree/b'
mkdir: created directory `tree/b/subdir/'
mkdir: created directory `tree/c'
mkdir: created directory `tree/c/subdir/'
removed `tree/b/subdir/c.txt'
removed `tree/b/subdir/b.txt'
removed `tree/b/subdir/a.txt'
removed directory: `tree/b/subdir'
removed `tree/a/subdir/b.txt'
removed `tree/c/subdir/b.txt'
No longer exists: "tree/b/subdir"
No longer exists: "tree/b/subdir/c.txt"
No longer exists: "tree/b/subdir/b.txt"
No longer exists: "tree/b/subdir/a.txt"
No longer exists: "tree/a/subdir/b.txt"
No longer exists: "tree/c/subdir/b.txt"
```